# How to download a module's source using cpan command?

Tags: perl, cpan

Is it possible to download a Perl Module's source using `cpan` command? How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at [the cpan man page](http://perldoc.perl.org/cpan.html), we see that that's what "cpan -g Modulename" does

```
   -g module [ module ... ]
       Downloads to the current directory the latest distribution
       of the module.
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Yet, this command doesn't seem to download the sources on my system. It seems to be doing nothing. I'm running it like `cpan -g Net::SNMP` and nothing gets downloaded to the current directory.

Comment: Hrm. When I run that command, I end up with Net-SNMP-v6.0.1.tar.gz in the current working directory. Does it complain or anything when you run it?

Answer (score 2):

The `look` interactive command

```
cpan> look Modulename
```